# Formatting numbers in Velocity Templates?

Tags: java, velocity

I need to display the amount in the following formats:

1099 -> 1,099.00
100 -> 100.00
100.251 -> 100.25
10999 -> 10,999.00
1110999 -> 11,10,999.00

Right now I am using the following code to display the amount:

```
$numberTool.format("#0.00", $credit);
```

In this case, if the amount is 1099, then it displays 1099.00
but I want to display this amount in this format:- 1,099.00

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the handling of the grouping separator:

```
$numberTool.format("###,##,###.00", $credit);
```

Comment: in your case it displays the comma but I need to display 2 decimal also. in your code it is not showing value up to 2 decimals.

Comment: I have tried your code..it shows value 1099 to 1,099
But required value has to be (1,099.00)like this

Comment: Couldn't it be `"###,###,##0.00" ?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta :this is also not working. I am not getting value up to 2 decimal .:-(

Comment: But `##` is a comment in Velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##,##,###.00");
System.out.println(nf.format(1099));
```

Output :

```
1,948.00
```

Is it what you are wanting.

Comment: let me verify it.
but is there any way to write code in velocity template to format numbers?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem like this

```
#set ($result = $number.format('#,##0.00', "10000.5"))
$result
```

The result will be 10,000.50